# How to show tab with external link from other pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple tabs on "single-page.html"...

```
<div class="tabs">
   <div class="tab-opt">
      <ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="#impressum">Impressum</a></li>
         <li><a href="#datenschutz">Datenschutz</a></li>
         <li><a href="#agb">AGB</a></li>
         <li><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-content">
       <div id="impressum" class="tab" style="display: block;">
            ...
       </div> 
       <div id="datenschutz" class="tab">
            ...     
       </div>
       <div id="agb" class="tab">
            ...    
       </div>
       <div id="credits" class="tab">
            ...      
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function () {
        $(".content-tabs .tab-opt ul li a").on('click', function (e) {
            $(".content-tabs .tab-opt ul li").removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            $(".content-tabs .tabs-content > div").hide();
            var hrefId = $(this).attr('href');
            $(hrefId).fadeIn().show();
        });
    });
```

I want to put links in footer and be able to show some tab on "single-page.html" from any page.

Example:
On homepage, with link in footer:

```
<a href="/single-page.html#agb">AGB</a>
```

I want to open "single-page.html" and show "AGB" tab...

Comment: Presumably, you have some JavaScript which runs when one the links is clicked. Run it when the page loads too. Take the input about which tab to show from a different place.

Comment: Use `location.hash` when page loads to get the `#agb` from url. Not enough known about your tabs code to provide any more detail

Comment: I updated the post with jquery function for tabs...